# How can I set the rows to be the attributes and columns the samples in rapidminer?

Tags: rapidminer

I have an excel file with data where the columns are the samples and the rows the attributes. I can't transpose the data, because the rows exceed the maximum number of columns. When I load this data into rapidminer, it automatically sets the columns as attributes and the rows as samples.

How can I set the columns as samples and the rows as attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean that you can't transpose the data *in Excel* because of the row limitation, the shortest answer is to start your process in RapidMiner with the desired Read operator (Import - Data - Read CSV or Read Excel) and then use the RapidMiner's Transpose operator (Data Transformation - Rotation - Transpose).

Make sure to select "first row as names" in the Read... operator, if appropriate.