# Get Rapidminer to transpose/pivot a single attribute/column in a table

Tags: transpose, rapidminer

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
ID         City       Code
"1005AE"  "Oakland"   "Value1"
"1006BR"  "St.Louis"  "Value2"
"102AC"   "Miami"     "Value1"
"103AE"   "Denver"    "Value3"
```

And I want to transpose/pivot the `Code` examples/values into column attributes like this:

```
ID         City       Value1    Value2   Value3
"1005"  "Oakland"     1         0        0
"1006"  "St.Louis"    0         1        0
"1012"   "Miami"      1         0        0
"1030"   "Denver"     0         0        1
```

Note that the `ID` field is numeric values encoded as strings because Rapidminer had trouble importing `bigint` datatypes. So that is a separate issue I need to fix--but my focus here is the pivoting or transposing of the data.

I read through a few different Stackoverflow posts listed below. They suggested the Pivot or Transpose operations. I tried both of these, but for some reason I am getting either a huge table which creates `City` as a dummy variable as well, or just some subset of attribute columns.

[How can I set the rows to be the attributes and columns the samples in rapidminer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089583/how-can-i-set-the-rows-to-be-the-attributes-and-columns-the-samples-in-rapidmine)

[Rapidminer data transpose equivalent to melt in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048768/rapidminer-data-transpose-equivalent-to-melt-in-r)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In pivoting, the `group attribute` parameter dictates how many rows there will be and the `index attribute` parameter dictates what the last part of the name of new attributes will be. The first part of the name of each new attribute is driven by any other regular attributes that are neither group nor index and the value within the cell is the value found in the original example set.

This means you have to create a new attribute with a constant value of 1; use `Generate Attributes` for this. Set the role of the ID attribute to be ID so that it is no longer a regular attribute; use `Set Role` for this. In the `Pivot` operator, set the `group attribute` to be `City` and the `index attribute` to be `Code`. The end result is close to what you want. The final steps are, firstly to set missing values to be 0; use `Replace Missing Values` for this and, secondly to rename the attributes to match what you want; use `Rename` for this.

You will have to join the result back to the original since the pivot operation loses the ID.

You can find a worked example here http://rapidminernotes.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/worked-example-using-pivot-operator.html

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I tried this and got most of the way there. I created the new attribute and set the role . . . Now I am getting the pivoted `Code` column correctly, but the `ID` column seems to be missing in the results. I wrote the results of the pivot to a csv and when I import the file, the `ID` column is missing. Did I miss a setting or something?

Comment: The `Pivot` operation loses the ID.  Use `Multiply` to take a copy of the original, `Select Attributes` to select ID  and City and `Join` to this to the aggregated result. I am assuming that there is a 1 to 1 mapping between ID and City.